# Set timeout for shell script, to make it exit(0) when time is over

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

When I set up a Jenkins job and found a problem about timeout for shell script.

It works like this:

Start Jenkins → `control.sh` is launched → `test1.sh` is launched in `control.sh`

Part code of `control.sh` is like:

```
#!/bin/sh
source func.sh     

export TIMEOUT=30
# set timeout as 30s for test1.sh

( ( sleep $TIMEOUT && function_Timeout ) & ./test1.sh ) 
# this line of code is in a = loop actually
# it will launch test2.sh, test3.sh... one by one
# later, I want to set 30s time out for each of them.

function_Timeout() {
  if [ ! -f test1_result_file]: then
    killall test1.sh
    # the test1_result_file will not 
    # be created if test1.sh is not finished executing.
  fi
}
```

part of func.sh is as below

```
#!/bin/sh
function trap_fun() {
  TRAP_CODE=$?
  { if [ $TRAP_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "test aborted"
    else
      echo "test completed"
  } 2>/dev/null

trap "trap_fun" EXIT
```

After `control.sh` is launched by Jenkins job, the whole `control.sh` will be terminated when time is over, and the line of `killall test1.sh` is reached, and the Jenkins job stop and fail.

I guess it's because `test1.sh` is killed and exit code is not `0`, so it cause this problem.

So my question is, is there someway to terminate or end the sub-script (launched by the main one, like `control.sh` in my case) exit with code `0`?

Updated on July 1:

Thanks for the answers so far, I tried @Leon's suggestion, but I found the code 124 sent by timeout's kill action, is still caught by the trap code - trap "trap_fun" EXIT, which is in func.sh.

I added more details. I did a lot google job but still not found a proper way to resolve this problem:(

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: @123 thanks for the reply! Can you specify how to trap it in test1.sh? Sorry I'm new to Shell

Comment: - Why are you using a subshell?
- What is `f_Timeout`? I only see `function_Timeout` defined in your sample code.

Comment: @Fara sorry for my typo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem finally, I added the code below in each testX.sh.

```
trap 'exit 0' SIGTERM SIGHUP
```

It is to make test1.sh exit normally after it receives killall signal.

Thanks to all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) utility from *`coreutils`*:

```
#!/bin/sh

timeout 30 ./test1.sh
status=$?
if [ $status -eq 124 ] #timed out
then
    exit 0
fi
exit $status
```

Note that this is slightly different from your version of timeout handling, where all running instances of `test1.sh` are being terminated if any one of them times out.

Comment: Thanks Leon! I tried your way, but I just found there's trap "trap_func" EXIT code, the 124 code is still caught by the trap "trap_func" EXIT :(, and the jenkins job fail and quit.

Comment: what happens if test1.sh also returns exit code 124 before the timeout? then the logic will be failed. I'm facing that issue.